# Como puedo poner el nombre y apellido de esa lista, dentro de los inputs respectivamente? al presionar el boton

Tags: javascript

```
<p>Nombre:</p>
<ul>
  <li>Marco</li>
  <li>Pérez</li>
</ul>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Presiona</button>

<form id="hola">
  <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
  <input id="demo" type="text" name="fname" ><br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
  <input id="demo2" type="text" name="lname" value=""><br>
</form>
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SO. Cómo has intentado ponerlos?? Si quieres que te ayudemos debes demostrar que has intentado hacer algo. Aquí ayudamos con errores... no hacemos el trabajo de los demás! Te recomiendo que leas [ask] y hagas el [tour] para entender cómo funciona SO y cómo elaborar una pregunta correctamente. Para más info puedes echar un vistazo en [help].

Comment: Recorres la lista, obteniendo los textos de los `li` y luego los añades a los `value` de los input. ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Qué te bloquea? ¿Podrías poner el código? Te recomiendo leer el [tour] de bienvenida y conocer lo que es un [mcve]

Comment: Por favor, podrías proveer mas información sobre como has intentado resolver el problema? Te recomiendo que sigas lo que dice @Benito-B , de una manera mas cordial por supuesto, bienvenido a Stackoverflow